# Got email of 85% Amazon RDS used in Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance to host my site using the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

I received this email:

> Dear AWS Customer,
>
> Your AWS account has exceeded 85% of the usage limit for one or more AWS Free Tier-eligible services for the month of September.
>
> AWS Free Tier Usage as of 09/29/2019:
>
> - **AWS Free Tier:** 17.1331 GB-Mo
> - **Usage Limit:** 20 GB of database storage, in any combination of RDS General Purpose (SSD) or Magnetic storage

But I just have a 2.1 Mb of Database.

What to do?

Comment: Could you update a better answer here now that you have been using it for long? I just received the same email. Could such email be just ignored as my DB size is in MBs only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From AWS [Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=278403) Posted by:  BrianW@AWS

> You should not be getting this message. The free tier is based on
>   **allocated storage, not consumed storage**. If you allocate a 20 GB
>   database, you will not exceed the free tier no matter how much you
>   insert into the database. We will on making sure these e-mails are
>   more helpful in the future.

So 20 GB is allocated storage for one year and you consume more for the month of September which is 2.1MB so based on 20GB for the year, you have to manager for each month accordingly.

Comment: even if that's for a year.. 2.1MB don't sums up to be 85% used as per month even

Comment: see the answer the reason is "you can allocate 20GB and use it for the whole month. This will consume 100% of the monthly allocation of the free tier, which is fine. It will continue each month like that."

Comment: But his question as well as mine is how can the RDS be 85% full if it contains nothing?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too (albeit a couple of years later :).  I created the instance 2 days ago and barely anything in it.  I was told that i created my db instance with an allocation of 200gb (doesn't matter what you store is what you allocate).  they divide the allocation by 30 and then each day of that month the storage increases according to what that figure is .   see chat below:

What is confusing for me is why it was created with 200gb in the first place.  I'm pretty sure I accepted defaults on the creation of the instance , and being that I opted for free tier the default should have been 20.  anyway that's what happened.  Also i deleted the instance but if i create another then the usage that was calculated will carry on to the new instance so no free storage for me after all.

"When it comes to creating RDS instances, you are charged not for what you store but the storage you provisioned. Although the instance is now deleted, I can see you originally allocated 200 GB. AWS does a calculation where this allocated storage is divided by 30 and then each day, you will see the storage usage increases on the billing console. If you provisioned 200 GB and this is divided by 30, by the third day you have reached almost 20 GB of usage. That's why you got the alert. "

Answer (score 0):

If you used the 20GB for a *portion* of the month, then it would be charged based on that portion.

So, you can allocate 20GB and use it for the whole month. This will consume **100% of the monthly allocation of the free tier**, which is fine. It will continue each month like that.

Please note that the Free Tier for Amazon RDS is only available for the first 12 months of your AWS Account.

Comment: But same as the OP, I've recieved this email even when my application is in testing mode and the database barely contains anything, two-three rows of data and I've used 85.7% of RDS which equates to 17.14 GB. How can this be possible if I've nothing in my database and this is what OP asked. Is there some logs which keeps generating and cover space, although logs should not cover this much space?.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar When you create an Amazon RDS instance, you assign the disk to be used by the database. You are charged for the whole allocated disk, regardless of how much is "used". So, if you allocated a 20GB disk, then that will fit within the Free Tier. You probably hit 85.7% because it has been running for 25 days.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein So you are charged by the time you hold that strorage and not by how much you use of it right? So I'm guessing after your first 12 months of the free tier you'll be charged the full price of the 20 GB that is alocated to your RDS instance regardless if it's in use or not, right?

Comment: @GherbiHicham Yes, that is correct.